# Как поменять адреса IPv4 и Прокси с помощью команды netsh?

Tags: cmd, proxy, dns, netsh, ipv4

С помощью команды netsh в bat файле нужно сменить ip4-адреса, маски, шлюзы, предпочитаемый и альтернативный dns, а также прокси.
Также хочется знать, как сменять с помощью netsh переключатели на: получить ip и dns адрес автоматически.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `netsh interface ipv4 set address`, `netsh interface ipv4 set dnsservers`.